# What are the limitations of appendChild method?

Tags: javascript, dom, append

Is it possible to append a second child into the first appendchild created in a single line of code?

Something like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some Text)));
```

This works fine, but i want to know why it doesn't work the same way in a single line of code.

```
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some Text'));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should append the paragraph first, so this code

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some Text)));
```

should be like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some Text')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some Text')));
```

evaluates to

```js
const p = document.createElement('p');
const node = document.createTextNode('Some Text');
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

because `document.createTextNode` is the last thing called, which returns the DOM node of the text

So when you run this, `'Some Text'` is added to the DOM, but it's not actually inside the `<p>` tag

Comment: @VLAZ [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZzcG.png) [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2JpD.png) [is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCW7s.png) (3 different screenshots)